# Fadak, Fatima and Abu baker

Tags: sunni, history, sahaba, ahl-ul-bayt, fatima-zahra

[Fadak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fadak) Belonged to Mohammad (PBUH).
He gave it to her daughter Fatima (PBUH) as a gift (see e.g.??).
It should have remained in her possession after he passed away.

Even if it wasn't given as a gift, 
its ownership should have passed onto Fatima (PBUH) as inheritance
as a personal property of Mohammad (PBUH).

But Abu Bakr took it away from her despite protests by her and her husband Ali (PBUH) 
and their testimonies.

I want to understand the Sunni perspective on this issue.

Why didn’t Abu Bakr accept Fadak as belonging to Fatima (PBUH)?
Did Abu Bakr based his ruling on Quran and the Prophet's Sunnah? If yes, what were the bases?
Do Sunni scholars consider Abu Bakr's ruling on the issue as righteous?

Comment: I tried to improve the question a bit and clarifying that the answers should explain the Sunni views on the issue (as the Shia view is obvious). If anyone knows a good hadith in the major Sunni hadith books confirming the story as stated in the question please add a link to in place of ??.

Comment: After Refusing it to give it to fatimah Razi-allahu-anhu He(Abu Bakr Razi-allahu-anha) went to Her home and not came out until Fatimah Razi-allahu-Anhu and Hazrate Ali(Razi-allahu-anha) agree with the decision of Abu Bakr(Razi-allahu-anha) .So no protest.

Comment: Please Plz. Don't take it other way around means Fatemah raziallahu-anhu is the lord of Paradise's women. and she like to live simple life. And Abu Bakr is the Siddique (as prophet sallahu-alaihiwassalm said)so he will not defalcate or breach the trust of prophet peace be upon him.

Comment: The recent revision makes this question too broad. A particular topic could be too broad therefore you are advised to break it down into separate question and not ask all in one. Please go through [ask].

Comment: I would like to know about the persons who gave testimonies in this case. Was it someone other than Ali RadhiAllahu anhu?

Answer (score 4):

A Sunni view on the issue is that these are not accurate.

First, it is not established that the prophet gave Fadak to her.
Contrary to that there are hadith stating that she asked for it during the prophet's lifetime but the prophet refused her request. See e.g. [Sunnan Abi Dawood; Kitab Al-Kharaj, Wal-Fai' Wal-Imarah; hadith 2966].

Abu Bakr refused the inheritance argument by narrating from the prophet that 
the inheritance does not apply to prophets property. See e.g. [Bukhari, Book 53, Volume 4, Hadith 325].

References:

- http://islamistruth.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/fadak-truth-vs-falsehood/
- http://www.chiite.fr/en/sahaba_02.html

And Allah knows best.

---

> [Sunnan Abi Dawood; Kitab Al-Kharaj, Wal-Fai' Wal-Imarah; hadith 2966]:
>   [...]
>   Umar ibn Abdul-Aziz gathered the family of Marwan when he was made caliph and said:
>
> > "Fadak belonged to the Apostle of Allah (Peace Be Upon Him), and 
> >     he made contributions from it, 
> >     showing repeated kindness to the poor of the Banu Hashim from it, and 
> >     supplying from it the cost of marriage for those who were unmarried. 
> >     Fatima asked him to give it to her, but he refused. 
> >     That is how matters stood during the lifetime of the Apostle of Allah (Peace Be Upon Him) till he passed away.
> >     When Abu Bakr was made ruler he administered it as the prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) had done in his lifetime till he passed on. 
> >     Then when Umar ibn al-Khattab was made ruler he administered it as they had done till he passed on. 
> >     Then it was given to Marwan as a fief, and it afterwards came to Umar ibn Abdul-Aziz.
> >     I consider that 
> >     I have no right to something which the Apostle of Allah (Peace Be Upon Him) refused to Fatima, and 
> >     I call you to witness that I have restored it to its former condition; 
> >     meaning in the time of the Apostle of Allah (Peace Be Upon Him)."

---

> [Bukhari, Book 53, Volume 4, Hadith 325]
>   Narrated Aisha:
>   Fatima sent somebody to Abu Bakr asking him to give her her inheritance from the Prophet 
>   from what Allah had given to His Apostle through Fai 
>   (i.e. booty gained without fighting). 
>   She asked for the Sadaqa 
>   (i.e. wealth assigned for charitable purposes) of the Prophet at Medina, and Fadak, and what remained of the Khumus (i.e. one-fifth) of the Khaibar booty.
>   Abu Bakr said:
>
> > Allah's Apostle said: "We (Prophets), our property is not inherited, and whatever we leave is Sadaqa, but Muhammad's(Sallalahu Alaihiwassalam) Family can eat from this property, i.e. Allah's property, but they have no right to take more than the food they need."
> >     By Allah! I will not bring any change in dealing with the Sadaqa of the Prophet 
> >     (and will keep them) as they used to be observed in his life-time, and 
> >     I will dispose with it as Allah’s Apostle used to do."
>
> Then Ali said: 
>   "I testify that none has the right to be worshiped but Allah, and that Muhammad is His Apostle. O Abu Bakr! We acknowledge your superiority."
>   Then Ali mentioned their own relationship to Allah's Apostle and their right.
>   Abu Bakr then said: "By Allah in whose hands my life is. I love to do good to the relatives of Allah's Apostle rather than to my own relatives. 
>   Look at Muhammad through his family 
>   (i.e. if you are no good to his family you are not good to him)."

EDIT :

One simple comment to add here that the decision of Abu Bakr R.A. was right therefore Ali R.A in his Caliphate did not give Fadak to the children of Fatima R.A or took it for himself etc. If this was ever happened in the era of Ali R.A there would be a reference.

Comment: @down-voters: if you think the answer is not well-sourced or not well-written then please help improve it. (Also keep in mind that [disagreement with a view is not an acceptable reason for down-voting](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/746).)

Comment: This is an open dispute and I don't what to have it here but I was wondering what any authority the testimony by Umar ibn Abdul-Aziz may have on this question. The man was not even born back then!